# Using gerund at the beginning of bullet points: What is more common, better or correct?

Tags: gerunds, lists, gerund-vs-infinitive

Is it correct or common to use the gerund at the beginning of bullet points? Which of the following examples is more common, better or correct? What are the pros and cons? Can I use the gerund?

1. Example (with gerund):

   - Establishing new universities
   - Strengthening the fight against drugs
   - Promoting E-learning
2. Example (with infinitive):

   - establish new universities
   - strengthen the fight against drugs
   - promote E-learning
3. Example (with noun)

   - The establishment of new universities
   - The strengthening of the fight against drugs
   - The promotion of E-learning

Comment: As well as the bare infinitive, you could add to your list the full infinitive : 'To establish new universities' etc.

Comment: It would depend on how you introduce it. If it is 'our aims are to...' then (2) works. If you say, 'I'll be discussing the following issues in the talk' then (1) or (3) fits better imo.